# Parallel.ForEach maintain collection order?

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library, parallel.for

Is there a way to guarantee order when using `Parallel.ForEach()`?  The collection I am looping over needs to maintain it's order but I was looking for some performance improvement.

Comment: What do you mean by "guarantee order"? For example, if you have 5 threads and item 3 finishes before item 4 then thread 3 will start with item 6, and as this goes on you are not certain about the order. Is that the problem you are trying to solve?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

no, the ForEach is only to be used for conditions where order doesn't matter; try [Parallel.For](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460703.aspx)

Comment: Would Parallel.For maintain the order of my collection?

Comment: I guess I should ask what you're trying to maintain order for -- is it like James Black said and you want to process the items in your IEnumerable? or is it that you want to make sure that what goes in comes back out in the same order? If it's the latter, they you should be fine with either a for or a foreach. If it's the former then you may not want to use the Parallel functions since operating on the items in sequence defeats the gain from operating them in parallel.

Comment: I am using StringBuilder.WriteLine() inside my foreach, creating a row of data that is already sorted

Comment: depending on how you're sorting your data, you may be able to put the sort functionality into a parrallel parallel loop, though I'd recommend just using the built in .NET options for that. In the end, I don't think that a parallel loop is the right solution for you since you need sequential operations.

Comment: This is incorrect. Parallel.For will not maintain ordering of the input data WRT to any output any more than Parallel.ForEach will. See my answer below. I have to down vote this because it's incorrect.

Comment: Please edit Parallel.For to Parallel.ForAll. +1 to #Ade-Miller for this!

Answer (score 10):

So you have a statement that looks something like this? (based on your comments above).

```
Parallel.Foreach(myData, ..., (d) =>
{
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  sb.Append(d);
  // WriteLine sb?
});
```

There are a number of issues with this approach.

1. Neither `Parallel.For` or `Parallel.ForEach` will guarantee that your access to the contents of `myData` are accessed in any particular order.
2. if you are a method on Console or a shared `StringBuilder`
   to either output the results or build up a complete string then you
   are probably blocking on a shared resource, effectively serializing
   parts of your parallel loop.

It's hard to say more without seeing a concrete example of your code. Depending on what you are doing you might be able to use the order preservation `AsOrdered()` in PLINQ to get where you want.
 See [this MSDN Resource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460677.aspx) and
[Ordered PLINQ ForAll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5352491/ordered-plinq-forall)

This will allow you to return an ordered result set, based on the input order but *not* guarentee the ordering of the actual processing.
However if parallel query is blocking on a call within the body you're unlikely to get good performance.

Answer (score 10):

In order to retain the order you must try to order the list before passing it to foreach loop since by default the Parallel.Foreach treats the list as unordered.

Example :

```
Parallel.ForEach(
list.AsParallel().AsOrdered(), 
(listItems) => {<operations that you need to do>});
```

Answer (score 1):

Did this as an extension method

```
 public static IEnumerable<T1> OrderedParallel<T, T1>(this IEnumerable<T> list, Func<T, T1> action)
    {
        var unorderedResult = new ConcurrentBag<(long, T1)>();
        Parallel.ForEach(list, (o, state, i) =>
        {
            unorderedResult.Add((i, action.Invoke(o)));
        });
        var ordered = unorderedResult.OrderBy(o => o.Item1);
        return ordered.Select(o => o.Item2);
    }
```

use like:

```
var result = input.OrderedParallel(o => YourFunction(o));
```

Hope this will save you some time.

Comment: How to use it? When I put OrderedParallel on List<int> collection I get the error The type arguments for method 'IEnumerable<T1> OrderedParallel<T,T1>(this IEnumerable<T>, Func<T,T1>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

Answer (score -1):

For anybody looking for a simple solution, I have posted 2 extension methods (one using PLINQ and one using `Parallel.ForEach`) as part of an answer to the following question:

[Ordered PLINQ ForAll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5352491/ordered-plinq-forall/20929046#20929046)