# Read large txt file multithreaded?

Tags: c#

I have large txt file with 100000 lines.
I need to start n-count of threads and give every thread unique line from this file.

What is the best way to do this? I think I need to read file line by line and iterator must be global to lock it. Loading the text file to list will be time-consuming and I can receive `OutofMemory` exception. Any ideas?

Comment: Show us what you have tried

Comment: create unique n random numbers, order in ascending order, use `File.ReadLines`, take lines at correct positions and pass them to threads

Comment: Can't you use this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460720.aspx ?

Answer (score 43):

You can use the [File.ReadLines Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503.aspx) to read the file line-by-line without loading the whole file into memory at once, and the [Parallel.ForEach Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783359.aspx) to process the lines in multiple threads in parallel:

```
Parallel.ForEach(File.ReadLines("file.txt"), (line, _, lineNumber) =>
{
    // your code here
});
```

Comment: I agree. The only thing I wanna add is that ReadLines enumerable should be partitioned. Because each parallel execution should be for something heavy.

Comment: Something to keep in mind: Parallel.Foreach will spawn a bunch of 'workers', then wait until *all* of them are done and only then spawn the next bunch of workers. So if processing time per line can differ it'd be advisable to use Jake Drew's approach (producer/consumer pattern)

Comment: Here can be thrown OutOfMemory Exception if the file is too large.

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/wX7VhA may be of interest @SteffenWinkler. Note that the 3rd item starts after the 1st ends - not after the 2nd ends. I am not convinced your bunching concern is valid.

Comment: @mjwills Huh, after some further playing around/testing I have to agree with you. My initial observation must have been a coincidence or I didn't pay enough attention to what was going on. However, one thing I would like to note is that Parallel.Foreach seems to divide the list of entries into the amount of threads available and each thread executes a sublist. So thread 1 gets entries 1 - 20 and thread 2 gets entries 21 - 40 instead of just taking the next entry available.

Comment: Yep, it does partition like that. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5352491/ordered-plinq-forall/20929046#20929046 may be worth a read if you don't want that behaviour.

Comment: Also consider removing your earlier (incorrect) comments.

Comment: Small correction that may leads to error. The third parameter of the lambda function (body) should be called "readingIndex". As human, the first line is numbered 1 and not 0, but as programmer, we are used to have the first element index of an array to be 0 (although it can differ, but nowadays pretty rare).

Answer (score 26):

After performing my own benchmarks for loading 61,277,203 lines into memory and shoving values into a Dictionary / ConcurrentDictionary() the results seem to support @dtb's answer above that using the following approach is the fastest:

```
Parallel.ForEach(File.ReadLines(catalogPath), line =>
{

});
```

**My tests also showed the following:**

1. File.ReadAllLines() and File.ReadAllLines().AsParallel() appear to run at almost exactly the same speed on a file of this size.  Looking at my CPU activity, it appears they both seem to use two out of my 8 cores?
2. Reading all the data first using File.ReadAllLines() appears to be much slower than using File.ReadLines() in a Parallel.ForEach() loop.
3. I also tried a producer / consumer or MapReduce style pattern where one thread was used to read the data and a second thread was used to process it.  This also did not seem to outperform the simple pattern above.

**I have included an example of this pattern for reference, since it is not included on this page:**

```
var inputLines = new BlockingCollection<string>();
ConcurrentDictionary<int, int> catalog = new ConcurrentDictionary<int, int>();

var readLines = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    foreach (var line in File.ReadLines(catalogPath)) 
        inputLines.Add(line);

        inputLines.CompleteAdding(); 
});

var processLines = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    Parallel.ForEach(inputLines.GetConsumingEnumerable(), line =>
    {
        string[] lineFields = line.Split('\t');
        int genomicId = int.Parse(lineFields[3]);
        int taxId = int.Parse(lineFields[0]);
        catalog.TryAdd(genomicId, taxId);   
    });
});

Task.WaitAll(readLines, processLines);
```

**Here are my benchmarks:**

[image]

**I suspect that under certain processing conditions, the producer / consumer pattern might outperform the simple Parallel.ForEach(File.ReadLines()) pattern.  However, it did not in this situation.**

Comment: Hi Jake, thanks for sharing the benchmark. While I agree that it's essential to use `File.ReadLines()` to avoid large memory consumption, does `Parallel.ForEach(File.ReadLines())` really outperform single thread processing? A stream is a sequential by design and also the hardware only supports reading one thing a time so by using multiple threads to process the result may increase overheads of blocking and context switch; it would be interesting to see the performance metrics of simply processing the result of `File.ReadLines()` using a single thread.

Comment: Go for it! It's easy enough to benchmark.  To answer your question, I think it depends on how much processing to each line that your foreach loop is performing. Think of a scenario where the stream is providing work to the thread pool in the Parallel.ForEach() each line that is read in, is then passed to the next available thread for processing.  If you have an empty for each loop, then reading with a single thread might be faster.  However, this is typically not the case.

Comment: While the stream may be sequential by design, it is also implemented as an IEnumerable which uses Yield Returns. As a result, in a single or muti threaded scenario, the File.ReadLines() behaves the same "yielding" processing until the next line request, rather from a single or multiple threads.  It will all really boil down to how much work you are doing on each file line regarding the speed up (if any) you get from parallel processing!

Comment: I noticed that the BlockingCollection is really slow. Perhaps this would be faster with a different backingstore.

Answer (score 7):

Read the file on one thread, adding its lines to a [blocking queue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312.aspx). Start `N` tasks reading from that queue. Set [max size](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267301.aspx) of the queue to prevent out of memory errors.

Answer (score 5):

Something like:

```
public class ParallelReadExample
{
    public static IEnumerable LineGenerator(StreamReader sr)
    {
        while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            yield return line;
        }
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        // Display powers of 2 up to the exponent 8:
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("yourfile.txt")

        Parallel.ForEach(LineGenerator(sr), currentLine =>
            {
                // Do your thing with currentLine here...
            } //close lambda expression
        );

        sr.Close();
    }
}
```

Think it would work. (No C# compiler/IDE here)

Comment: What about re-write it using             thr = new Thread[j];
            for (; i < j; i++)
            {
                thr[i] = new Thread(new ThreadStart(go));
                thr[i].IsBackground = true;
                thr[i].Start();
            } not Parallel.ForEach

Comment: @obdgy: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: @obdgy what use does that have compared to Parallel.ForEach?

Comment: @obdgy using 100-300 threads has no speed benefit if you are running on a dual, quad or octa core. It might even be slower than running just 8 threads on a octa core. Putting it simple: running more threads than CPU cores will only slow down the process.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to limit the number of threads to `n`, the easiest way is to use `AsParallel()` along with `WithDegreeOfParallelism(n)` to limit the thread count:

```
string filename = "C:\\TEST\\TEST.DATA";
int n = 5;

foreach (var line in File.ReadLines(filename).AsParallel().WithDegreeOfParallelism(n))
{
    // Process line.
}
```

Comment: If I understand `File.ReadLines()` correctly it is basically a sort of python-like generator, using Yield internally?

Comment: @DaanTimmer I don't know anything about Python, but File.ReadLines() just returns an IEnumerable<string> which is implemented via `yield`

Comment: In that case, your answer can be consolidated to, yes :-)

Answer (score 2):

As @dtb mentioned above, the fastest way to read a file and then process the individual lines in a file is to:
1) do a File.ReadAllLines() into an array
2) Use a Parallel.For loop to iterate over the array.

[You can read more performance benchmarks here.](http://cc.davelozinski.com/c-sharp/the-fastest-way-to-read-and-process-text-files)

The basic gist of the code you would have to write is:

```
string[] AllLines = File.ReadAllLines(fileName);
Parallel.For(0, AllLines.Length, x =>
{
    DoStuff(AllLines[x]);
    //whatever you need to do
});
```

With the introduction of bigger array sizes in .Net4, as long as you have plenty of memory, this shouldn't be an issue.