# Faster data checking and updating inside foreach loop

Tags: c#, linq

I'm reading data from StreamReader line by line inside the following while statement.

```
while (!sr.EndOfStream)
{
   string[] rows = sr.ReadLine().Split(sep);

   int incr = 0;
   foreach (var item in rows)
   {
       if (item == "NA" | item == "" | item == "NULL" | string.IsNullOrEmpty(item) | string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(item))
       {
           rows[incr] = null;
       }
       ++incr;
   }
    // another logic ...
}
```

The code works fine but it is very slow because of huge csv files (500,000,000 rows and hundreds of columns). Is there any faster way how to check data (if it is "NA", "", ... should be replaced by null). Currently I'm using foreach with incr variable for updating item inside foreach.

I was wondering about linq or lambda would be faster but I'm very new in these areas.

Comment: linq is unlikely to be any faster. One minor thing you can do is get rid of the 'item == ""' check as you already have string.IsNullOrEmpty(item), also the | between the IsNullOrEmpty and IsNullOrWhitespace checks won't short-circut change that to ||.

Comment: I suggest you save your data from CSV to database (relational or NoSQL on the circumstances), and then work with it. It will be fast.

Comment: What is `// another logic`? Loop (`for` is a better choice than `foreach`) should be quite fast

Comment: Another logic is SqlBulkCopy part. But this is not the object of this task.

Comment: I'm reading data from StreamReader line by line so rows seems like logical name for variable in this case. First part of bottleneck is data checking inside while statement and second seems to be bulk copy which I'll post in the separated task.

Comment: Check out this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17188357/read-large-txt-file-multithreaded

Comment: Have you profiled the program? The title mentions data checking inside the loop, but I would have thought that the time to do the checking and updating would be insignificant compared to the time to read from the file and split into columns (what you call rows)

Comment: Reading data from flat file across the lines (what you call columns) doesn't seem to be bottleneck. I'm trying to figure out how to speed up bulkcopy procedure. This should help program's performance.

Comment: And then adding to datatable as row (dt.Rows.Add(rows)). I would stay in "rows" approach.

Comment: `dt.Rows.Add(rows)` In that case, `row` would be a better variable name.

Comment: :-) definitely improves my solution

Answer (score 5):

Firstly, don't use `foreach` when changing the collection, it's not a good habit, especially when you already use a counter variable.

This loop could be made multi-threaded using `Parallel.For` this way:

Code using normal for:

```
while (!sr.EndOfStream)
{
    string[] rows = sr.ReadLine().Split(sep);

    for (int i = 0; i < rows.Length; i++)
    {
        //I simplified your checks, this is safer and simplier.
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(rows[i]) || rows[i] == "NA" || rows[i] == "NULL")
        {
            rows[i] = null;
        }
    }
    // another logic ...
}
```

Code using `Parallel.For`

```
while (!sr.EndOfStream)
{
    string[] rows = sr.ReadLine().Split(sep);

    Parallel.For(0, rows.Length, i =>
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(rows[i]) || rows[i] == "NA" || rows[i] == "NULL")
        {
            rows[i] = null;
        }
    });
    // another logic ...
}
```

**EDIT**

We could approach this from another side, but I don't recommend this, because this requires a **LOT** of RAM, because it has to read the entire file into memory.

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("test.txt");
Parallel.For(0, lines.Length, x =>
{
    string[] rows = lines[x].Split(sep);

    for (int i = 0; i < rows.Length; i++)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(rows[i]) || rows[i] == "NA" || rows[i] == "NULL")
        {
            rows[i] = null;
        }
    }
});
```

But I don't think that this is worth it. You decide. These kinds of operations don't play well with parallelization, because they take so little time to compute, that it is too much overhead.

Comment: If performance is really important do not forget to limit the number of thread of Parallel For https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.paralleloptions.aspx

Comment: I tried normal loop, parallel loop and my original foreach approach. Foreach and normal loop is almost the same but slowest is surprisingly parallel loop.

Comment: @mateskabe Did you check it in release mode?

Comment: Yes, I'm testing the approaches only in release mode

Comment: @mateskabe Maybe this?

Comment: Thanks for that. The files are unfortunately very huge so this isn't good idea from RAM point of view.

Comment: @mateskabe Yeah, I think you should use a simple for, and maybe make the method async, so it doesn't freeze your application.

Comment: Yes, I'll try to play around bulkcopy method as well. Thank you very much for your time!